# Can you enter Mexico with a temporary UK residence permit?

Tags: visas, mexico, nigerian-citizens, uk-residents

I hold a Temporary Residence Card in the U.K. and I am a Nigerian citizen. This is not a Permanent Residence Card, known as Indefinite Leave to Remain, but a Temporary Leave to Remain Residency Permit. I want to travel to Mexico on holiday, but I am unsure if I should apply for a visa.

I'm seeing a lot of different information online from different Mexican embassies, and the lack of consistency throughout their different consulate websites is fairly worrying. I even emailed the Mexican consulate in London and their response was "to avoid inconvenience you should apply for a visa," not answering my question at all.

Has anyone travelled to Mexico with a Temporary Residence Permit? As far as I'm aware, this is a multiple entry U.K. visa that lets us live, work, and study in the U.K., but it is known as a Residence Permit that isn't stamped in your passport, but is a card on its own.

Answer (score 5):

[Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx) is the database used by airlines to check visa requirements.

According to Timatic, for Nigerians visiting Mexico:

> Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> Visa Exemptions: Passengers with a permanent residence permit issued
> by United Kingdom for a maximum stay of 180 days.

There is no mention of temporary residence permits and since you're emphatic that you don't have a permanent residence permit it seems that you **will** need a visa.