# Can I travel to Mexico with a UK BRP?

Tags: mexico, uk-residents

I am an Indian national (Indian passport holder) and I am residing in the UK on a Tier 2 work permit visa. I have a UK BRP card (Biometric Residence Permit). Can I travel to Mexico without a Mexican visa? Has anyone travelled to Mexico on a UK BRP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you enter Mexico with a temporary UK residence permit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126047/can-you-enter-mexico-with-a-temporary-uk-residence-permit)

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll need a visa

> Visa required.
>
> Visa Exemptions
>
> Passengers with a permanent residence permit issued by United Kingdom
> for a maximum stay of 180 days. Warning
>
> Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.

A Tier 2 visa is not a Permanent Residence Permit (or Indefinite Leave to Remain as its called in the UK) nor is it a visa (in reference to that [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82917/do-indian-passport-holders-with-uk-tier-2-need-to-get-a-tourist-visa-for-mexico?rq=1)) as you have a UK BRP